# clear react cache in the server

Tags: reactjs, react-cache

I have this method to cache the db query using **react cache**:

```
import { cache } from "react";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
const getSession = cache(async (token: string) => {
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
const user_id: string = decoded.id;
const client = await connectToDatabase();
const user = await client.db("users").collection("users").findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(user_id), is_active: true });
if (!user) {
    return null;
}   
return {
    user: {
        id: user._id.toString(),
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
    },
    token: token,
};
```

});

Is there away to clear the cache in **server side component** at updating user data or at logout?
I have tried to make `caches.delete(token);` but give me caches undefined.

so caches is only work with browser not with node js.
Any idea how the react cache work? and how to clear it?

Comment: I don't see variable caches in your code

Comment: and I don't see cache in react API description =)

Comment: There is no such thing as `React.cache`. Which version of React are you using?

Comment: please look for this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3m-MZkuadU